# Hidden Message: The Army Message

Tags: chess

A soldier of the International Army received a message which shows 2 pictures of a finished chess game (shown below) with the text; **The White Army stood still, while the Black Army dashed**. What is the message contain within this 2 images?

[image: first board]

[image: second board]

This puzzle require an additional information on a certain thing, but the information regarding to what that thing is, is already given. The final answer will be in text form (words).

Comment: The first game isn't finished. H5-D1 prolongs the game one move. I mention this because my first thought was that there would be something wrong with the boards.

Comment: @JoelRondeau ah.... I didn't actually noticed that... (how shameful). Fortunately it doesn't affect the answer in any way.

Comment: Do you have any more of these?

Comment: @d'alar'cop "these" as in more puzzles? Unfortunately not quite (I have some but they're kinda same as the ones I've posted). So now, I need to go back to the drawing board for a bit ^^;

Comment: @moonRabbit They were interesting and original. Good job

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The obvious place to look for words from a chess board is algebraic chess notation, but after looking at a cheat sheet for a few minutes, it doesn't seem like there's any clear way to assemble a message from that.

So, well, it's a military scenario, and we have the word "dashed" in the message, maybe morse code? In that case, white would be dots and black dashes. Going row by row from top to bottom, that'd give us:

```
 -      T
..      I
-...    B
-...    B
.-      A
.-.     R

.-..    L
.-..    L
..      I
-.-     K
```

Oh, wait, the rows on a chess board are numbered from bottom to top, we need to reverse it. So that makes the message "KILL RABBIT"

Comment: Wow, I know I made this one easier than the last.. but I wasn't expecting it to be solved this fast. Was it too simple, or too straight-forward or something (just asking for future reference)?

Comment: @moonRabbit I thought it was a good level of difficulty. Lots of possible red herrings. I went down a few dead ends before getting the right answer. I think how fast a puzzle is solved is a very imprecise way of measuring its difficulty

Comment: Oh no, I wasn't worried on the how fast it was solved (although I am surprised). I was just wondering if it's too straight-forward that people don't have to think much to solved. But since you've said that you hit a few dead ends before reaching the answer, I guess it's still fine.

Comment: "stood still" references the dots or "stops" in the morse.

Comment: ♪Kill da wabbit, kill da wabbit♫